# Adding specific fields from a csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add specific values from a CSV file if the user is the same. I can't explain it clearly so I will try to show you.

```
=====================
|E-mail  | M-count |
|a@a.com | 12      |
|b@a.com | 8       |
|a@a.com | 13      |
|c@a.com | 2       |
=====================
```

Then it tries to add everything that belongs to a specific user:

```
=====================
|E-mail  | Total   |
|a@a.com | 25      |
|b@a.com | 8       |
|c@a.com | 2       |
=====================
```

I split the CSV and added the values that I need in a set, but I can't think of a way to add the values that I need. Any ideas?

Edit:

This is what my CSV looks like:

```
p_number,duration,clnup#
5436715524,00:02:26,2
6447654246,00:17:18,5
5996312484,00:01:19,1
5436715524,00:10:12,6
```

I would like to get the total duration and the total clnup# for each unique p_number. I am sorry for the confusion but the table above was just an example.

Comment: better to show us some fragment of the file and some code of what you have done

Comment: I edited the post. Regarding the code, it's currently just reading the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an  `OrderedDict`  storing the names as values and updating the count as you go:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()

with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    head = next(r)
    for name,val in r:
        od.setdefault(name, 0)
        od[name]  += int(val)

print(od)
OrderedDict([('a@a.com', 25), ('b@a.com', 8), ('c@a.com', 2)])
```

To update the original file you can write to a NamedTemporaryFile then use shutil.move to replace the original after you have written the rows with writerows using the od.items:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
od = OrderedDict()

with open("test.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    head = next(r)
    wr.writerow(head)
    for name,val in r:
        od.setdefault(name, 0)
        od[name]  += int(val)
    wr.writerows(od.iteritems())


move(out.name,"test.txt")
```

Output:

```
E-mail,M-count
a@a.com,25
b@a.com,8
c@a.com,2
```

If you don't care about order use a defaultdict instead:

```
import csv

from collections import defaultdict
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
od = defaultdict(int)

with open("test.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    head = next(r)
    wr.writerow(head)
    for name,val in r:
        od[name]  += int(val)
    wr.writerows(od.iteritems())
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is actually really interesting, it never came to mind that I could use this method. I will try it out!

Comment: @user5000054, no worries, this presumes the data is as posted and delimited by a comma

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

ifile = open('sample.csv', 'rb')
csv_reader = csv.reader(ifile)

d = {}
for row in csv_reader:
    d[row[0]] = int(row[1]) if d.get(row[0], None) is None else d[row[0]] + int(row[1])
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

Comment: @user5000054, You many want to skip the first row of input csv if it contains header.